# Авторизация на Yii2

Tags: yii2

Пробую сделать авторизацию на yii2. Создал форму и когда ее отправляю, получаю такую ошибку

```
Argument 1 passed to yii\web\User::login() must implement interface yii\web\IdentityInterface, null given, called in /frontend/models/auth/LoginForm.php on line 79 and defined
```

Происходит это, как я понял, при вызове

```
Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
```

Почитав в интернете, я нашел решение, но оно не помогло так как мой класс ***User*** и так создан правильно

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
```

Что сделать, что бы не было этой ошибки?

Comment: `> Argument 1 ... null given ...` ... Ваш метод `$this->getUser()` возвращает `null`, а не сущность пользователя. Покажите его нам ...

Comment: Вы переопределяли клас WebUser?Посмотрите на реализацию метода login, в старых версиях он принимал один параметр вместо двух. Попробуйте обновить аккуратно фреймворк

Comment: @Ninazu, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#login()-detail ... Вы так далеко на фреймворке не уедете, если при каждом подобном простом ислючении будете обновлять фреймворк.